# Вытянуть имя и фамилию по email

Tags: php, ldap

Всем добрый день. Хочу в форме при вводе мыла, выводить имя и фамилию.

Коннект и привязка к AD через ldap модуль получается через `ldap_connect()` и `ldap_bind`. А вот дальше как сформировать запрос пока не знаю. Можно подсказку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получилось! Вот пример.

```
$srv = "10.10.10.10";
$srv_domain = "domain.kz";
$srv_login = "artem@".$srv_domain;
$srv_password = "pass";
$dn = "dc=domain, dc=kz";
$LDAPFieldsToFind = array("sn","givenname");
$SearchFor="Artem";              
$SearchField="samaccountname";
$filter="($SearchField=$SearchFor*)";

$connect = ldap_connect("ldap://".$srv);
ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$r = ldap_bind($connect,$srv_login,$srv_password);
if ($r){
    $sr=ldap_search($connect, $dn, $filter, $LDAPFieldsToFind);
    $result_ent = ldap_get_entries($connect, $sr);
    print($result_ent[0]['givenname'][0].' '.$result_ent[0]['sn'][0]);
}
```

источник здесь 
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ldap-search.php